# How to add single method to handle multiple routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

my rails application is a proxy server for some rest API services It means all the request for the rest server is routing through my rails app. I have defined all require routes in my routes.rb file and I have written different methods for each routes in my controller. So instead of different methods for each route I want a single method in my controller where I can check the request.fullpath and based on request parameters redirect it to appropriate rest service call

Here is my routes look like

```
  get '/lookup/location/search', to: 'ticketing#lookup_location_search'
  get '/lookup/company/search', to: 'ticketing#lookup_company_search'
  get '/lookup/assignmentGroup/search', to: 'ticketing#lookup_assignment_group_search'
  get '/lookup/ci/search', to: 'ticketing#lookup_ci_search'
  get '/lookup/user/search', to: 'ticketing#lookup_user_search'
```

For each route there is a separate method exist in controller instead of that i want a single method which would further call correct rest URL based on request parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use wildcard routes for you'r issue like this:

```
# routes.rb
get '/lookup/*other_parts', to: 'ticketing#proxy_action' , format: false
# maybe with constraints
# get '/lookup/*other_parts', to: 'ticketing#proxy_action' , format: false,  constraints: { other_parts: /.../ }  

# within your controller
def proxy_action
  case params[:other_parts] 
    when 'location/search'
        ...
    when 'assignmentGroup/search'
       ...
    ...
    else
      ...
  end
```

Comment: @adrian yes, your right. I did mean case. I did correct my code.

Comment: So when you are matching the other part in switch statement then how to match with dynamic data? e.g- 'location/:location_id/search'

Comment: @Sunny can you explain it in a little bit more detail? You didn't mention this in your question. I don't know if I get it right. You can still add more routes like `get '/location/:location_id/*other_parts', to: 'ticketing#proxy_action' , format: false` You only have to ensure that the most general rule comes at last.

Comment: So in my routes I kept the common route to redirect it to single controller action like
match '/ticketingService/*other_parts' => 'ticketing#proxy_action', via: [:get,:put,:post]
In the controller using switch case based on matching routes I am rendering some mock json but now I am facing issue if routes has some dynamic data.
How I can match below route in my switch case as it contain location_id and it's dynamic   
'/location/:location_id/*other_parts'

Comment: When both routes differ that much I would not handle it with one action. I would use 2 actions and extract common logic to a `private` method. This simplyfies the `case` statement a lot and would be more object oriented in my point of view. Any way if you want to do it in one action you can first check if `params[:location_id]` is present and handle the special logic needed before you go on to the `case` statement.